# Landcover Legend

Tags: legend, land-cover, land-use

When I download landcover, the legend for pseudocolouring is always a number rather than the actual legend which was shown where I downloaded the data. How would I go about getting the actual land use as the legend?

Comment: Feel free to [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/326390/edit) your question so it contains a) the software you're using, b) the source of your data and c) how your data is displayed there.